# Black screen during installation ubuntu 12.10 via wubi on HP Pavillion g6-1273s1

Tags: wubi, laptop, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I tried to install ubuntu 12.10 alongside win7(64bit) on HP pavilion g6-1273sl.
The installation process went well until the "reboot" step. The computer rebooted and started to processing something in dos mode. After he was finished the screen went black and the last thing I heard was the drumming sound, I think it is the sound when you enter ubuntu. I waited for about 10 minutes and nothing happened, I tried to press enter or space key, but nothing happened. Then I force shutdown the computer and tried to turn it back on. Then I was asked if I want to run ubuntu or win 7, I choose ubuntu and the purple blank screen appeared, then appeared the loading dots and after that the black screen again. Anyone help?
P.S. sory for bad english:)

Comment: Yes, the drumming sound is the sound of the login screen.  Try looking at [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/44179) question.